# If $T$ be a compact normal and $c\in\sigma(T)$ (spectrum of $T$), $c\ne 0$. Prove that, $c$ is an eigenvalue of $T$

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory, compact-operators

Here $\sigma(T):=\{c\in\Bbb{C}|\ T-cI\text{ is not invertible}\}$. I know that the above result holds for compact,self adjoint operators.

I can write $T=A+iB$ where $A=\frac{T+T^*}{2}$ and $B=\frac{T-T^*}{2i}$. Here $A,B$ is compact and self adjoint operator with $AB=BA$ (Since $T$ is normal).

I think anyhow I need to use the result for **compact, self-adjoint operator** (on $A,B$ possibly) to prove the similar result for $T$ (compact, normal).

But I am not getting any idea how to proceed. Can anyone help me in this regard? Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Did you mean to write "normal" instead of "self adjoint" in the title?

Comment: It would be better to make another title and to put the title in the main body

Comment: Yes yes Sorry for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $v$ be an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$. Then
$$
\lambda B v = B \lambda v = BA v = AB v,
$$
so $Bv$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$ too. Hence $B \ker (A - \lambda I) \subset \ker (A - \lambda I)$. And the same holds for $B$.

Denote $(\alpha_i)_{1\le i \le N_A}$ and $(\beta_j) _{1\le j\le N_B}$ the sequences of non-zero eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$ respectively.

Therefore, for each eigenvalue $\alpha_i$ of $A$ and for each eigenvalue $\beta_j$ of $B$ $\ker (A - \alpha_i I) \cap \ker (B - \beta_j I)$ is an invariant subspace for both $A$ and $B$. Let $(\varphi^{ij}_k)_{1\le k \le N_{ij}} $ be an orthonormal basis of this subspace (or just one zero vector if the intersection is zero). Hence
$$
A =  \sum_{i = 1}^{N_A}\sum_{j = 1}^{N_B}\sum_{k=1}^{N_{ij}}\alpha_{i} \langle \varphi_{k}^{ij}, \cdot \rangle \varphi_{k}^{ij},
$$
$$
B =  \sum_{i = 1}^{N_A}\sum_{j = 1}^{N_B}\sum_{k=1}^{N_{ij}}\beta_{j} \langle \varphi_{k}^{ij}, \cdot \rangle \varphi_{k}^{ij}.
$$
(I used the Hilbert—Schmidt decomposition here).

Therefore,
$$
T =  \sum_{i = 1}^{N_A}\sum_{j = 1}^{N_B}\sum_{k=1}^{N_{ij}}(\alpha_{i}+i\beta_j) \langle \varphi_{k}^{ij}, \cdot \rangle \varphi_{k}^{ij}.
$$

Comment: Yes I have proved this. But how the result follows from this step?

Comment: @DeltaEpsilon $T$ has the diagonal form, so each non-zero point of its spectrum is $\alpha_i + i \beta_j$ for some $i$ and $j$, which is clearly an eigenvalue

Comment: OKay I got it, thanks